# substance painter export gltf in webgl(three.js) is totally black

Tags: three.js, gltf

When I import my model (`.fbx`) to draw a texture in the substance painter and export it to the `.gltf` format, I find that the metal I paint is gone and replaced [by the shiny black](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), and then when I put the exported model in the three`.js/examples/webgl_load_gltf.html` case, I found that my model was dark and needed to be added a `directLight` can only see a point, the effect is not very good, but the case of importing the painter painter does not have any problems.

It looks as good as the model in the original example.

I would like to know what causes this two problems.

Comment: Please always share your model data with all assets when asking such questions.

Comment: hold on, I will put the detail of this trouble to github

Comment: https://github.com/tackor/WebGL-SubstancePainter-GLTF-Trouble/blob/master/Illustarte/Readme.md

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your demo has only a single instance of `HemisphereLight`. The materials of your meshes are instances of `MeshStandardMaterial` with `metalness` values of `1.0`. Since hemisphere lights are sources of indirect diffuse light, they are not reflected by pure metals. More information about this topic in: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9228

You should use a different light setting e.g. add a directional light. Or try to fix the material settings in your model.

Comment: "Your metalness is `Napalm Death` level, it should be more `Black Sabbath`"

Comment: thanks first, but actully I have log the child.material.  both model's material.type are `MeshStandardMaterial` and metalness = 1. but the model one totally black and the other is good

Comment: you can see this:   https://github.com/tackor/WebGL-SubstancePainter-GLTF-Trouble/blob/master/Illustarte/Readme.md

Comment: I know that add a directionalLight can be more better, but if I put the gltf made from substance painter'demo, that ok, just the gltf made from my mbx will got this trouble

Answer (score 0):

**DUDE I JUST WENT THROUGH THIS**, it was a nightmare.  I had a very shiny gold car with windows and all types of shit going on.  Looked great as a USDZ!  Then tried to export GLTF. Black. 
 Turned off all channels except normal and base color, looked fine.

Then went and turned on metallic and again black.

Then i realized "Oh, I didn't bake my mesh maps" like an idiot.  Boom, metallic, roughness and opacity all suddenly worked.

Always ALWAYS bake your mesh maps.  Substance is pointless without it.

I know this is 2 years old but apparently all the early adopters of Substance figured this out long ago, so this is for you, random person just learning this stuff.  AR is only going to become more in demand, thank god I know how to make it cross-platform now.